# How do I safely put two variable sized datatypes (structs) in a single struct?

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to construct some C structs that themselves need to hold multiple structs. It looks something like this:

```
typedef struct hdr_t {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d[3];
    uint64_t e;
    uint8_t f[];
} hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t data;
} pyld_t;

typedef struct {
    hdr_t hdr;
    pyld_t pyld;
} msg_t;
```

When I compile this, depending on the compiler and settings, I get warnings.

```
./file.h:55:24: warning: field 'hdr' with variable sized type 'hdr_t'
      (aka 'struct hdr_t') not at the end of a struct or class is a GNU extension
      [-Wgnu-variable-sized-type-not-at-end]
    hdr_t hdr;
```

For this example, I'm using clang 6.1.0:

> $ clang --version
>   Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
>   Thread model: posix

The warning complain that what I'm doing is a non-portable GNU extension, which I'd rather avoid. What can I do to solve this? Is there not a safe way to put multiple structs in a struct? Surely that's not the case.

Comment: You can't. You *can*, however, have a struct with *pointers* to structs with flexible array members.

Comment: Can you give the full declaration for `A_t` and `B_t`

Comment: Only the last field of a struct can have a variable size. You will like need to use a pointer to another object for one or both of the structs you want to 'hold'.

Comment: What are members of A_t and B_t?

Comment: @LPs, I've fleshed out structs A_t and B_t a little more if it helps.

Comment: The compiler diagnostic you presented does not correspond to the code you presented.  The types `A_t` and `B_t` are not variable-size.  With those declarations, there should not be any problem with the declaration of type `C_t`.  If `clang` really barfs on that, as you presented it, then it would constitute a bug.  I think it more likely, however, that you have simplified the real problem right out of your example.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Could you elaborate? I used to use the same "technic" for packet (header, payload) to cast buffer, but gcc never give me warnings? Is that a clang "feature?

Comment: @WesleyBland Is the edited code the real code?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, I see how my example didn't provide the same problem. Now I've updated to include the real code (with simplified variable names).

Comment: You could use a union to store different size, instead of use f[].

Comment: @LPs It's a feature, not a "feature".

Comment: @n.m. When I wrote the code posted was different. The `f[]` there wasn't and I didn't understand why clang could warn on a struct with some fields like `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`.

Comment: What do you want `offsetof(msg_t, pyld)` to be?

Comment: Why do you want to have an header with an unknown size?

Answer (score 2):

A C structure can be variable-size only in the sense that it may contain a "flexible array member" as its last member.  C forbids such a structure type from being the type of *any* structure member or array element, though GCC permits that as an extension.

Even if GCC (or clang) accepted your declaration, I doubt it would mean what you think it means.  Every member of a structure has a fixed offset relative to the beginning of the structure, determined statically at compile time.  As a result, your `msg_t` cannot provide sufficient space for arbitrary `hdr.f`, and quite possibly it provides no space at all, especially if you enable structure packing.  Thus, accessing `hdr.f` of a `msg_t` could easily access the message `data`, which I suppose is not what you expect.

I guess the whole point is to map a structure to a byte buffer, but if the underlying data format has variable-length elements in the middle then you just can't directly map a single C structure to it.  You could, however, create and use an index structure:

```
typedef struct {
    hdr_t *hdr;
    pyld_t *pyld;
} msg_index_t;
```

That would make it easier to handle mapping a *pair* of structures to your buffer.

Comment: @chux, read a bit further.  Both C11 and C99 forbid a structure containing a flexible array member from being an array element or a member of another structure.  In C11 this is at the end of 6.7.2.1/3.  C11 is in fact more restrictive than C99 in this regard, as it applies the same prohibition to unions containing a such a structure, possibly recursively, as it does directly to such structures.

Comment: Excuse my incorrect reading of this fine answer.  Taking down previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an union:

```
typedef struct {
    ..stuff
}type_f1;

typedef struct {
    ..stuff
}type_f2;

typedef struct {
    ..stuff
}type_f3;

typedef union {
    type_f1 f1;
    type_f2 f2;
    type_f3 f3;
    uint8_t rawdata[MAX_RAWDATA];
}type_f;

typedef struct hdr_t {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d[3];
    uint64_t e;
    type_f f;
} hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t data;
} pyld_t;

typedef struct {
    hdr_t hdr;
    pyld_t pyld;
} msg_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of solutions that will fix the issue. For my specific problem, just changing the declaration of `hdr_t` from this:

```
typedef struct hdr_t {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d[3];
    uint64_t e;
    uint8_t f[];
} hdr_t;
```

to this:

```
typedef struct hdr_t {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d[3];
    uint64_t e;
    uint8_t *f; //Use pointer instead of variable sized array
} hdr_t;
```

I'm not sure why the original code was using the array, but it wasn't necessary.

Comment: If you are mapping your struct layout directly to the packet format, e.g. you are doing `read` or `write` with the entire struct, then the array *is* necessary. If you are doing I/O with individual members, then it's not.